# D3 v7 merge() pattern removes wrong nodes & links

Tags: javascript, node.js

I struggle to properly redraw the provided D3 forced graph. As soon as I delete a node, which is NOT the last node, the binding/assignment between link and node is broken. The belonged linktext is either wrong or written on top of an existing.

**What I am doing?**

On node click I retrieve the node id, which I use to retrieve the correct link array index, by comparing them the source.id and to find the correct node array index position too. Further I use the results to finally splice the link and node array at the correct position.

**So whats my problem?**

For example I delete node number 3, which should delete the node array object at position 2, which is true. Further the link between 3 --- 1 should be removed from the link array object at position 1 as well, which is also true.

[image]

At the end I restart the data assignment and call the restart() function. Which should use the modified nodes and links array´s to merge and redraw the graph. It actually does redraw but the link text is wrong.. instead of node 3 node 5 was deleted.

Help.

[image]

```js
        var data = {
            "nodes": [{
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
            }
            ],
            "links": [{
                "source": 2,
                "target": 1,
                "text": "2 --- 1"
            },
            {
                "source": 3,
                "target": 1,
                "text": "3 --- 1"
            },
            {
                "source": 4,
                "target": 1,
                "text": "4 --- 1"
            },
            {
                "source": 5,
                "target": 1,
                "text": "5 --- 1"
            }
            ]
        };

        let nodes = data.nodes
        let links = data.links

        //Helper
        let nodeToDelete

        var width = window.innerWidth,
            height = window.innerHeight;

        var buttons = d3.select("body").selectAll("button")
            .data(["add node", "remove node"])
            .enter()
            .append("button")
            .attr("class", "buttons")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d;
            })

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("size", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5000))
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id
            }).distance(250))



        linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkscontainer")
        nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")

        console.log("links_on_init", links)
        console.log("nodes_on_init", nodes)

        restart()

        simulation
            .nodes(nodes)
            .on("tick", tick)

        simulation
            .force("link").links(links)



        function tick() {
            linkLine.attr("d", function (d) {
                var dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x),
                    dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y),
                    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

                return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
            })

            node
                .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
        }

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = null;
            d.fy = null;
        }

        buttons.on("click", function (_, d) {
            if (d === "add node") {
                const newObj = { "id": nodes.length + 1,}
                const newLink = {"source": nodes.length + 1, "target": 1, "text": nodes.length + 1 + " --- " + "1"}
                
                nodes.push(newObj)
                links.push(newLink)

            } else if (d === "remove node") {
                if (nodeToDelete != undefined) {

                    let linkToDeleteIndex = links.findIndex(obj => obj.source.id === nodeToDelete.id )

                    let nodeToDeleteIndex = nodes.findIndex(obj => obj.id === nodeToDelete.id)

                    links.splice(linkToDeleteIndex, 1)

                    nodes.splice(nodeToDeleteIndex, 1)

                    console.log("links_after_removal", links)
                    console.log("nodes_after_removal", nodes)
                }
            }

            restart()
        })

        function restart() {

            // Update linkLines
            linkLine = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkPath")
                .data(links)

            linkLine.exit().remove()

            const linkLineEnter = linkLine.enter()      
                .append("path")
                .attr("class", "linkPath")
                .attr("stroke", "red")
                .attr("fill", "transparent")
                .attr("stroke-width", 3)
                .attr("id", function (_, i) {
                    return "path" + i
                })

            linkLine = linkLineEnter.merge(linkLine)
            
            // Update linkText
            linkText = linksContainer.selectAll("linkLabel")
                .data(links)

            linkText.exit().remove()

            const linkTextEnter = linkText.enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("dy", -10)
                .attr("class", "linkLabel")
                .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "linkLabel" + i })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("")
            
            linkTextEnter.append("textPath")
                .attr("xlink:href", function (_, i) {
                    return "#path" + i
                })
                .attr("startOffset", "50%")
                .attr("opacity", 0.75)
                .attr("cursor", "default")
                .attr("class", "linkText")
                .attr("color", "black")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.text
                })

            linkText = linkTextEnter.merge(linkText)

            // Update nodes
            node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".nodes")
                .data(nodes)
            
            node.exit().remove()

            const nodesEnter = node.enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "nodes")
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )

            nodesEnter.selectAll("circle")
                .data(d => [d])
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .style("stroke", "blue")
                .attr("r", 40)
                .on("click", function(_, d) {
                    d3.selectAll("circle")
                        .attr("fill", "whitesmoke")
                    d3.select(this)
                        .attr("fill", "red")

                    nodeToDelete = d
                })
             
            nodesEnter.append("text")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", 20)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.id
                })

            node = nodesEnter.merge(node)

            // Update and restart the simulation.
            simulation
                .nodes(nodes);
            simulation
                .force("link")
                .links(links)
           simulation.restart().alpha(1)
        }
```

```css
  .link {
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .nodes {
        fill: whitesmoke;
    }

    .buttons {
        margin: 0 1em 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
    <!-- D3 -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98a5e27706.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>


<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide data keys when you do `.data(data)`. So for example when you provide data to the nodes, you may pass key like this:

```js
    node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".nodes")
      .data(nodes, node => node.id) // Pass node.id as a key so d3 knows which node is a new and which one is old.
```

You can read about this here - https://observablehq.com/@dnarvaez27/understanding-enter-exit-merge-key-function

Also you've forgot to place `.` before class name when you adding text labels to the graph, that is why text was duplicated )

Here fixed example, **but since you are using array length as ids, there will be duplicates in ids for nodes and links, it will lead to unexpected results**, I consider to use uniq ids rather then indexes.

```js
  var data = {
"nodes": [{
  "id": 1
},
  {
    "id": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
  }
],
"links": [{
  "source": 2,
  "target": 1,
  "text": "2 --- 1"
},
  {
    "source": 3,
    "target": 1,
    "text": "3 --- 1"
  },
  {
    "source": 4,
    "target": 1,
    "text": "4 --- 1"
  },
  {
    "source": 5,
    "target": 1,
    "text": "5 --- 1"
  }
]
  };

  let nodes = data.nodes
  let links = data.links

  //Helper
  let nodeToDelete

  var width = window.innerWidth,
height = window.innerHeight;

  var buttons = d3.select("body").selectAll("button")
.data(["add node", "remove node"])
.enter()
.append("button")
.attr("class", "buttons")
.text(function (d) {
  return d;
})

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
  svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
}))
.append("g")

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
.force("size", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5000))
.force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
  return d.id
}).distance(250))



  linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkscontainer")
  nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")

  console.log("links_on_init", links)
  console.log("nodes_on_init", nodes)

  restart()

  simulation
.nodes(nodes)
.on("tick", tick)

  simulation
.force("link").links(links)



  function tick() {
linkLine.attr("d", function (d) {
  var dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x),
    dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y),
    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
})

node
  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
  }

  function dragStarted(event, d) {
if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
d.fx = d.x;
d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(event, d) {
d.fx = event.x;
d.fy = event.y;
  }

  function dragEnded(event, d) {
if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
d.fx = null;
d.fy = null;
  }

  buttons.on("click", function (_, d) {
if (d === "add node") {
  const newObj = { "id": nodes.length + 1,}
  const newLink = {"source": nodes.length + 1, "target": 1, "text": nodes.length + 1 + " --- " + "1"}

  nodes.push(newObj)
  links.push(newLink)

} else if (d === "remove node") {
  if (nodeToDelete != undefined) {

    let linkToDeleteIndex = links.findIndex(obj => obj.source.id === nodeToDelete.id )

    let nodeToDeleteIndex = nodes.findIndex(obj => obj.id === nodeToDelete.id)

    links.splice(linkToDeleteIndex, 1)

    nodes.splice(nodeToDeleteIndex, 1)

    console.log("links_after_removal", links)
    console.log("nodes_after_removal", nodes)
  }
}

restart()
  })

  function restart() {

// Update linkLines
linkLine = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkPath")
  .data(links, link => link.text) // ADD DATA KEY FOR LINK

linkLine.exit().remove()

const linkLineEnter = linkLine.enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "linkPath")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("fill", "transparent")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("id", function (_, i) {
    return "path" + i
  })

linkLine = linkLineEnter.merge(linkLine)

// Update linkText
linkText = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkLabel") // FIXED ClassName
  .data(links, link => link.text)  // ADD DATA KEY FOR TEXT

linkText.exit().remove()

const linkTextEnter = linkText.enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("dy", -10)
  .attr("class", "linkLabel")
  .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "linkLabel" + i })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("")

linkTextEnter.append("textPath")
  .attr("xlink:href", function (_, i) {
    return "#path" + i
  })
  .attr("startOffset", "50%")
  .attr("opacity", 0.75)
  .attr("cursor", "default")
  .attr("class", "linkText")
  .attr("color", "black")
  .text(function (d) {
    return d.text
  })

linkText = linkTextEnter.merge(linkText)

// Update nodes
node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".nodes")
  .data(nodes, node => node.id) // ADD DATA KEY FOR NODE

node.exit().remove()

const nodesEnter = node.enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragStarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragEnded)
  )

nodesEnter.selectAll("circle")
  .data(d => [d])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .style("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("r", 40)
  .on("click", function(_, d) {
    d3.selectAll("circle")
      .attr("fill", "whitesmoke")
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("fill", "red")

    nodeToDelete = d
  })

nodesEnter.append("text")
  .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", 20)
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("pointer-events", "none")
  .text(function (d) {
    return d.id
  })

node = nodesEnter.merge(node)

// Update and restart the simulation.
simulation
  .nodes(nodes);
simulation
  .force("link")
  .links(links)
simulation.restart().alpha(1)
  }
```

```css
  .link {
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .nodes {
        fill: whitesmoke;
    }

    .buttons {
        margin: 0 1em 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
    <!-- D3 -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98a5e27706.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>


<body>

</body>

</html>
```